# Hide CPT from search engine Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Let's suppose, (www.example/services/washing) - I need to hide (services) CPT, I tried this code but didn't work. Could somebody help?

```
add_action( 'init', 'update_my_custom_type', 99 );

function update_my_custom_type() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    if ( post_type_exists( 'services' ) ) {

        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['services']->exclude_from_search = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the CPT from search engines, add the below meta tag to your `header.php` file. Replace `your-cpt` with your custom post type you want to hide.

```
<?php if ( is_singular( 'your-cpt' ) ) { ?>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<?php } ?>
```